# In Google Maps Custom Marker not Showing in Samsung S8 or same version 7.0 in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am creating a Google Map with a custom latitude and longitude marker. The markers show properly on a Samsung S4 mobile, however they don't show on S8 or higher version. I grant all permission for that. I also put the click listener on the Custom Marker. These all work fine in S4 or low version, but not work in high version api mobile.

Where am I wrong? This is my code:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermission();
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
    String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the 
            documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    //            return false;
} else {

    mSetUpMap();
}


private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new
            String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

}

public void mSetUpMap() {
    googleMap.clear();
    /**Create dummy Markers List*/
    List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    for (City item : cityList) {

        if (googleMap != null) {
            Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new
                    LatLng(item.getLatitude(),
                    item.getLongitude())).title(item.getName()).anchor(0.5f,
                    0.5f).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker(
                    item.getDrawableId(), item.getName()))));
            markersList.add(m1);
        }

    }
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); //change for 
            (0, 1)if you want a fade in
            ani.setDuration(2000);
            ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }

            });
            ani.start();
            if (marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(0).getName())) {
                AppUtil.city = cityList.get(0);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(1).getName())) {
                AppUtil.city = cityList.get(1);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(2).getName())) {
                AppUtil.city = cityList.get(2);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(3).getName())) {
                AppUtil.city = cityList.get(3);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(4).getName())) {
                AppUtil.city = cityList.get(4);

            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction =
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new
                    CityDetailFragment());
            transaction.commit();
/*((CityDetailFragment) adapter.getItem(1)).setupData();
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,false);*/
            return true;
        }
    });

    /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
    builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    /**initialize the padding for map boundary*/
    final int padding = 150;
    /**create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera*/
    final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    /**create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map*/
    cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    /**call the map call back to know map is loaded or not*/

    googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                    padding));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap createStoreMarker() {
    ViewGroup continer = null;

    View markerLayout = view.inflate(null,
            R.layout.store_marker_layout, continer);

    markerLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),
            markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    final Bitmap bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    markerLayout.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: if it's showing in S4 then marker code is not the problem. Please post your code where you are asking for permissions.

Comment: i grant all permission

Comment: so you adding marker after you grant permissions? Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: first i grant all permissions and then set map and add markers

Comment: can't help you unless you add permission code.

Comment: i edit code for permission

Comment: where is your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method?

Comment: i edit my code @ Somesh Kumar

Comment: I think you haven't overridden `onRequestPermissionsResult` method. I have created a library [which helps with permission asking and other thing check it out](https://github.com/someshkumar049/PermissionMadeEasy) or you can try overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` and `mSetUpMap()` method there too.

Comment: ok i try @ Somesh Kumar